# how to pass an array in my recursive function php

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion

I have created a recursive function `scanFile` but I can't return an array with this function, It gives me an error when I want to push my `$array[$key]` in `$this -> fileArray` :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object
>   context in createSprite.php:75

```
class createSprite
{
    public $array;
    public $fileArray = array();

    function __construct($array)
    {
        global $argc;
        $this -> arr = $array;
        $this -> argc = $argc;
        $this -> fileArray = $fileArray;
    }

    public function recursiveGetImage()
    {
        if($this -> argc > 2)
        {       
                $fileArray = array();

                function scanFile($dir) 
                {
                    $array = glob($dir . '/*');

                    if (is_array($array)) 
                    {
                        foreach($array as $key => $file) 
                        {
                            if (is_dir($file)) 
                            {
                                scanFile($file);
                            }
                            elseif(is_file($file)) 
                            {
                               array_push($this -> fileArray, $array[$key]);
                            }
                        }                        

                    }
                }

                for($i = 1; $i < $this -> argc; $i++)
                {
                    if(is_dir($this -> arr[$i]))
                    {
                        var_dump(scanFile($this -> arr[$i]));
                    }
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Entrez plusieurs fichiers";
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use nested functions in classes - use another class method (`private` if it is only used internally), this will stop the problem...

```
private function scanFile($dir) {
...
}
```

Then call it using

```
$this->scanFile($file);
```